# Talk to iOS from windows?

Tags: iphone, ios, windows, mobile, usb

I have to communicate with iOS devices on windows. I'm looking to something similar to libimobiledevice which allows system services that iTunes is providing by default, such accessing to music, photos and etc. What's the best practice or library to do so? What about dependencies, such as iTunes and external libraries that have to be shipped along with the program?

Comment: What are you talking about? Hardware or Network or Bluetooth?

Comment: I'm looking for something similar to libimobiledevice

Comment: So if you want something similar to libmobiledevice, what is it about libmobiledevice that stops you using that?

Comment: The fact that it is not officially ported to windows and unofficial port is not updated regularly, and I failed to port it my self, so started this thread to get other alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

Check out Bonjour:

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/NetServices/Articles/about.html

Answer (score 1):

The Unofficial port for libimobiledevice could be an answer but it is not updated regularly :
http://www.bingtech.net/wordpress/2011/03/189/

Answer (score 1):

You can find a Windows build of imobiledevice here: http://quamotion.mobi/iMobileDevice/

Hope it helps,

Frederik.